# get "SSLError: [SSL: BAD_SIGNATURE] bad signature (_ssl.c:726)" exception when executing Python script on Android

Tags: python, ssl

I have a simple Python script runs pretty well on Python 2.7 on Windows 10.

> however it gives me
>
> ```
> "SSLError: [SSL: BAD_SIGNATURE] bad signature (_ssl.c:726)"
> ```
>
> error when I run it from Android.

the code is quite simple as below：

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import ssl
import traceback

#ssl._https_verify_certificates(False)
#ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

try:

    url="https://stackoverflow.com/"
    https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context(cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,check_hostname=False)
    https_handler = urllib2.HTTPSHandler(context=https_context)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(https_handler)
    rep=opener.open(url)
    print(rep.read())
except Exception, e:
    urllib.urlopen("http://c.seechentech.com/exception?code=484&error=%s&u=%s" % (traceback.format_exc(), url))
```

After some investigation, I found this exception is raised during socket handshake, but I have already set certificate verification to False (There's no needs to verify certificate for me), why it checks signature? How to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Please avoid posting code in images since it can't be copied/pasted into an ide for anyone to assist you. Instead, edit your question and post the code as text taking care to use the code formatting tools.

Comment: yes, I realized this and updated to a block of codes :)

Answer (score 1):

this issue has been resolved and I'd like to share my findings.

**Finding 1:**
Regardless set to verify certificate or not, OpenSSL socket, which called by Python Socket, will always do SSL handshake where PEM certificate is required. This finding answers why my code fails during socket handshake.

**Finding 2:**
Python is able to load system trusted CA from windows 10 default location, however, it fails on Android. It might be caused by two potential reasons:

1) Python could not find default CA location on Andorid which is /system/etc/security/cacerts/

2) Python expects CA to be PEM format, but Android trusted CA has additional lines after ---END CERTIFICAT--- which is a sign of end of CA content.

I did not verify which reason actually caused the failure of loading CA certificate. What I did to give Python proper CA data is combined all CA files I extracted from one Android device into a single file, and set to ssl.SSLContext with load_verify_locations method.

**Finding 3:**
There're some trusted CAs missing on Android comparing to trusted CAs on Windows, so I have to manually add them into my combined CA file.

**Finding 4:**
Python document says "If you want maximum compatibility between clients and servers, it is recommended to use PROTOCOL_SSLv23 as the protocol version" which is not true. It causes invalid certification error when I use this protocol version. ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1 protocol version works fine in my case.

**Finding 5:**
Python document says to give a certificate as an "ASCII PEM string" which is not right. We have to give a unicode string.

Here is the code for reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import sys
reload(sys) 
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
import os
from os import path
import urllib
import urllib2
import ssl

import traceback
import shutil


def loadCA():

    concatedCA = u'''
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
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
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
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
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
'''

    return  concatedCA


cadata = loadCA()

try:

    url="https://stackoverflow.com/"


    https_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    https_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    https_context.check_hostname = False
    https_context.load_verify_locations(cadata=cadata)

    https_handler = urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=1,context=https_context)

    redirect_handler = SmartRedirectHandler()

    opener = urllib2.build_opener(https_handler,redirect_handler)
    rep=opener.open(url)

except Exception, e:
    traceback.print_exc()
```